# Django why getting this error No user profile found matching the query

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to implement load more button so I am writing this view for load json data but I am not understanding why I am getting this error. `No user profile found matching the query Raised by: members.views.UserProfileUpdate`

here is my view:

```
class PostJsonListView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        upper = kwargs.get('num_posts')
        lower = upper - 3 
        posts = list(Blog.objects.values()[lower:upper])
        posts_size = len(Blog.objects.all())
        max_size = True if upper >= posts_size else False
        return JsonResponse({'data': posts, 'max': max_size}, safe=False)
```

this is my blog app
urls.py

```
path('posts-json/<int:num_posts>',PostJsonListView.as_view(),name='json-view')
```

this is my members app
urls.py

`path('<slug:slug>/', UserProfileUpdate.as_view(), name='update-profile'),`

if I put any wrong url like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/sassassdsadasdd/ giving me the same error `No user profile found matching the query Raised by: members.views.UserProfileUpdate`

Comment: The code snippet doesn't seem to be linked to the the error raised.

Comment: The view raising the error is not the one in your question

Comment: Please include the `UserProfileUpdate` view as this appears to be where your error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

you are in the `UserProfileUpdate` view, using the `slug` for getting the profile object like this:

```
Profile.objects.get(username=slug)
```

**but!**
you should use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut functions.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
get_object_or_404(Profile, username=slug)
```

[refrence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)